# PHP Reg Ex how to preg_match exactly 2 or 3 digits in phone number?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the reg ex to match a phone number. The format of the phone must be 2 or 3 digit number .I've tried multiple ways to approach this and can't get the digits in to work correctly. but it doesn't work. How to make it work?

> `['tel', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[0-9]+(5|11)$/i'],`

exmples:

```
33010
02133010428
```

Comment: Please provide examples of what needs to match. Your current code matches: 'one or more digits' followed by ' a 5 or a 11'.

Comment: How is `02133010428` a 2 or 3 digit number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare amount of symbols like this:

```
\d{2}
```

So "2 or 3 digits" equals:

```
\d{2}|\d{3}
```

Or

```
\d{2,3}
```

Comment: Not an expert, `\d{2,3}` would be the shorter version of `\d{2}|\d{3}`, right?

Comment: Yep! Funny, I was just about to edit it :D You, sir, are vigilant, my respect!